# Xamarin - How to add multiple hyperlinks

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, hyperlink

I am trying to add hyperlinks to labels on my Xamarin Forms page. For some reason only the first hyperlink function call works, and subsequent calls to my function `hyperlink()` seem to be ignored. I am unsure why it only works once.

I think it is because tapGestureRecognizer() can only handle one thing at once, but honestly I am not sure. How can I add hyperlinks to multiple labels on my Xamarin app?

Code for reference:

```
private void hyperlinkLabel(Uri uri, Label label)
    {
        var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => {
            Device.OpenUri((uri));
        };
        label.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
    }
```

And then I call it as such:

```
 hyperlinkLabel(new Uri("https://www.mycoolwebsite.com", NewAccountLabel), 
 hyperlinkLabel(new Uri("https://www.myothercoolwebsite.com"), RegisterLabel);
```

Comment: Have you tried to make a List<TapGestureRecognizer> and make it as globale variable?

Comment: No I haven't, thanks for the tip

Comment: its working for me... just add parenthesis in the first call of hyperlinkLabel method.

hyperlinkLabel(new Uri("https://www.mycoolwebsite.com", NewAccountLabel),